# ExtJS xtype registering

Tags: javascript, extjs3

I'm having some trouble with registering xtypes in ExtJS 3.3.1.

I'd like a compositefield with two string fields on it, but only one is shown.

Some help would be nice as I have been struggling with it for quite some time and I don't have a clue what could be wrong.
This is my code:

```
Ext.myApp.StringDouble = Ext.extend(Ext.form.CompositeField, {
    separator: '-',
    unitOptions: {},
    values: ['first', 'second'],
    bothRequired: false,

    init: function() {
        this.items = [];
        var unitConf = {
        };

        Ext.apply(unitConf, this.unitOptions);
        this.items.push(new Ext.form.TextField(Ext.apply({
            name: this.values[0] + '.' + this.name,         
            fieldLabel: this.fieldLabel + ' ' + this.values[0],
                value: this.value && this.value[this.values[0]]
        }, unitConf)));

        this.items.push(new Ext.form.DisplayField({
            value: this.separator
        }));

        this.items.push(new Ext.form.TextField(Ext.apply({
            name: this.values[1] + '.' + this.name,         
            fieldLabel: this.fieldLabel + ' ' + this.values[1],
            value: this.value && this.value[this.values[1]]
    }, unitConf)));

},

initComponent : function() {
    this.init();
    Ext.form.TextField.superclass.init.Component.call(this);
}

});

Ext.reg('stringdouble', Ext.myApp.StringDouble);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first of all i don't understand why you need to create your own component when passing config to compositefield can achieve same behavior, like this

```
{
    xtype: 'compositefield',
    labelWidth: 120
    items: [
        {
            xtype     : 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Title',
            width     : 20
        },
        {
            xtype     : 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'First',
            flex      : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

and also there is typo when calling parent class' initComponent method

```
initComponent : function() {
    this.init();
    Ext.form.TextField.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
}
```

Comment: These components serve as templates that can be modified by definitions (change label, unit, separator,...). They are used for something like stock keeping where a lot of items have similar parameters.